# How to fix grid pane not fitting underlying gridpane cell in javafx

Tags: javafx, resize, constraints, width, gridpane

so i have a grid pane and an image view both of size 1000. They are both placed on the game grid pane at the coordinates (0,1). They should be overlapping perfectly, but the grid pane is wider then the image view. I have tested it already if I set the width of the scene to 1000 it cuts the window of perfectly where the image view ends so the problem is that the grid pane is for some reason wider then 1000. how can that be?

Here is my controller code:

```
gameGrdPn.getColumnConstraints().get(0).setMinWidth(1000);
        gameGrdPn.getColumnConstraints().get(0).setPrefWidth(1000);
        gameGrdPn.getColumnConstraints().get(0).setMaxWidth(1000);
        gameGrdPn.getRowConstraints().get(1).setMinHeight(750);
        gameGrdPn.getRowConstraints().get(1).setPrefHeight(750);
        gameGrdPn.getRowConstraints().get(1).setMaxHeight(750);

        playingFieldGrdPn.getColumnConstraints().removeAll(playingFieldGrdPn.getColumnConstraints());
        playingFieldGrdPn.getRowConstraints().removeAll(playingFieldGrdPn.getRowConstraints());

        playingFieldGrdPn.setMinSize(1000, 750);
        playingFieldGrdPn.setMaxSize(1000, 750);
        playingFieldGrdPn.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        playingFieldGrdPn.setPadding(new Insets(0));
     playingFieldGrdPn.prefWidthProperty().bind(gameGrdPn.getColumnConstraints().get(0).prefWidthProperty());
        
        for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
            ColumnConstraints col = new ColumnConstraints(1);
            col.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
            playingFieldGrdPn.getColumnConstraints().add(col);
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < 750; y++) {
            RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints(1);
            row.setVgrow(Priority.NEVER);
            playingFieldGrdPn.getRowConstraints().add(row);
        }

        Image playingBoardImg = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("HaseUndIgelPlayingBoard.png"));
        ImageView playingBoardView = new ImageView(playingBoardImg);
        gameGrdPn.add(playingBoardView, 0, 1, 1000, 750);
        gameGrdPn.getChildren().get(4).toBack(); //sending imageView to back
```

and here is an image of the problem. Here the gaming pieces x cordinate is set to 1000. the grey area marks the grid pane.

[image]

I tried adjusting the size of the undelying panes to see what would happen, but that just resulted in the grid pane being cut off. Any kind help would be appreciated, since I am new to javafx!

Edit: I have figured out now that placing a gameStone expands the columnWidth. But how do I allow the picture to break the borders of its corresponding grid pane cell?

Here is the code i have so far:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        Image gamingPieceImg = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("gamingPieces/gamingPiece-"+i+".png"));
        ImageView gamingPieceView = new ImageView(gamingPieceImg);
        gamingPieceView.setFitHeight(60);
        gamingPieceView.setFitWidth(60);

        GridPane.setColumnSpan(gamingPieceView, 1);
        GridPane.setRowSpan(gamingPieceView, 1);

        playingFieldGrdPn.add(gamingPieceView, 1000, 350);
    }
```

Thanks in advance, Romina

Comment: It seems to me like GridPane isn't the right container class here.  For the game screen I'd be tempted to use a BorderPane with the Center populated with a StackPane with both the field and the background image in it.  For the right hand side, I'd just use a VBox.  Also, I'd be tempted to implement the big image as the background for whatever Pane is in the Center, set to stretch.  Then you'll never have issues with mismatches.

Comment: Is GridPane the right container for your playing pieces?  It seems like you want to have 1000 x 750 pixel resolution for placing the pieces, but the pieces themselves are bigger than the resulting GridPane cells would be.  You could do this by having the pieces Span several rows and columns.  At some point the pain and suffering of dealing with a GridPane for this is probably going to get to be too much.  Better perhaps, to just use a Pane, and then use translateX and translateY on each gaming piece to position it where it should go.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you for your answer. So could I place the gaming pieces directly on the image view then? Also your solution sounds much better, but I'll have to think twice about omitting the gridpane, since this is uni-project and my prof is quite the specific person with very unique requests, and I think judging from the project description she really wants us to implement this through a grid pane. But if nothing else helps I'll use your solution! Thank you for taking the time! :)

Comment: *"I think judging from the project description she really wants us to implement this through a grid pane."* -> I suggest you directly ask your professor if that is what is required.